# How to get a particular attribute from queryset in Django in view?

Tags: django

I have a query like this:

```
file_s = Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id=log_id)
```

Now, I want to get the files_id attribute from file_s in Django view. How can I do that?

Comment: list_files_id= [s['files_id'] for s in file_s.values('files_id')]

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) to get particular attribute which will return you list of dicts, like

```
file_s = Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id=log_id).values('files_id')
```

EDIT: If you want only one attribute then you can use `flat=True` to suggest to return just list of values. However, make sure in what order the list will be.

```
file_s = Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id=log_id).values_list('files_id', flat=True).order_by('id')
```

Comment: How can I get the Id only:[{'files_id': 1L}] from this in integer.

Comment: @user1881957, check the update, you can make use if `flat=True` parameter.

Comment: TypeError: values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flat'

Comment: @user1881957, oh yes, it should be `values_list`.

Comment: @Rohan : How can I remove duplicates in this list?

Comment: The `flat=true` parameter made my day, a +1 is not enough. Thanks @Rohan!

Comment: How can I get multiple values from values_list but not in list fromat?
something like:-
 file_s = Share.objects.filter(shared_id=log_id).values_list('files_id', 'f_name' flat=True)

Comment: @rohan `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'` I'm trying to get only the values for the names in a QuerySet of that returns pairs of `{'name': <insertnamehere>}`. Above is the error I get.
This is my qs (bad is a related name): 

`badguys=People.objects.filter(role="main")[0].bad.all()`
`names=badguys.values('name', flat=True).order_by('name')`

Answer (score 16):

Your `Share.objects.filter()` call returns a Djagno [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) object which is not a single record, but an iterable of filtered objects from the database with each item being a `Share` instance.  It's possible that your `filter` call will return more than one item.

You can iterate over the `QuerySet` using a loop such as:

```
for share in files_s:
    print share.files_id
```

If you know that your query is only expected to return a single item, you could do:

```
share = Share.objects.get(shared_user_id=log_id)
```

which will return a single `Share` instance from which you can access the `files_id` attribute.  An exception will be raised if the query would return anything other than 1 result.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get only the value from a single value QuerySet you can do:

```
file_s = Share.objects.filter(shared_user_id=log_id).values_list('files_id', flat=True).first()
```